# How to best maintain security with a contractor installing a PHP/CodeIgniter/MySQL app?

Tags: security, mysql, php, codeigniter

I've been working with an offshore developer on an alpha version of my web app.  He's going to be installing it on my server soon, and while I trust him, I also want to be prudent.  How can I structure his access to the server and MySQL to allow him to get the app running without exposing more than I need to?

I've already got Apache, MySQL, and PHP installed.

Answer (score 1):

You could shadow his session using Screen/SSH (see "[Collaboration with Screen](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-10sysadtips/)") -- create a user called "webinstall" or whatever and disable it when you're done.

Also if PHP and MySQL are already installed, I would strongly recommend installing it yourself; it's trivial to do so (assuming this is your typical LAMP application):

```
mysql -u <root or whatever> -p <your_database> < /path/to/mysql.dump
```

You'll feel better, trust me.  Give it a go -- you can always post back here for help.

Comment: Yeah, I'm inclined to do the install myself.  So the line you posted is importing the database, right?  That's the part that was making me a bit worried.  Crazy that it's that simple.  Thanks!

Comment: Yup, that's it.  You'll need to make sure that there's a user granted at least SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE permissions for your database, but like I said, get the code off of him, and post another question asking how, and we'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set up PHP and MySQL yourself and just give him FTP access to upload the framework and its files? CodeIgniter does not really need any special setup, and outside of PHP and MySQL everything else can be done via FTP.